# Google+ Share photo by iOS and Check if it was a "public" post

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, google-plus

I have an app that share photo and prefilled text with

```
[[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog]
```

Is it possible to check how the user had shared the image? As public or friends or something else. The only return method that I have found is this :

```
- (void)finishedSharingWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *text;

    if (!error) {
        text = @"Success";
    } else if (error.code == kGPPErrorShareboxCanceled) {
        text = @"Canceled";
    } else {
        text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error (%@)", [error localizedDescription]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Status: %@", text);
}
```

But it return only success/not success and relative error. It is possible to check the sharing permission that the user had select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is going to be calling [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) for the user shortly after the post is created and if the post is found it was public.